# como colocar una opcion por defecto en un boton select usando angular y bootstrap

Tags: angular, select, botón

Estoy tratando de hacer un boton select que tenga una opcion seleccionada por defecto (Panamá en este caso), el problema que tengo es que no me la muestra seleccionada, y descrubrí que es por el [(ngModel)] que tengo en el select, ese ngModel lo tengo ya que necesito saber el valor de la opcion que  selecciona el usuario para poder usarlo en el .ts, si quito el ngModel si me funciona el selected. que pasa ahí? no entiendo porque funciona sin el ngModel y con el ngModel no, alguien puede ayudarme? este es el código:

```html
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-2" > <h6 class="mt-2 text-center text-helvetica"> Seleccione un País </h6> </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <select class="form-control"  (change)="peticion2()" [(ngModel)]="pais">

        <option selected value="934">  Panamá </option>
        <option value="521" > Colombia </option>
        <option value="3000"> Venezuela </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa por el data binding bidireccional `[(ngModel)]="pais"` al hacer eso le dices al select que tome como valor seleccionado lo que se encuentra en `pais`. Una solución rápida sería que en tu archivo .ts inicialices la variable pais con el value de panamá `pais = 934`

Comment: Era eso amigo. Muchas Gracias!